# Goconvey causing panic with go routine on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, go, tdd, goconvey

I have a set of test that use GoConvey with Go 1.3.1 that work just fine locally. But when I trigger a build with Jenkins, with the Go 1.3.1 as well, I get a panic from Goconvey related to a go routine I use in my test.

The test may be seen here:

```
func TestListApplication(t *testing.T) {
    s := &Session{}
    s.Username = "foo"
    s.Password = "bar"
    ts := serveHTTP(t)
    defer ts.Close()
    s.Baseurl = ts.URL
    s.initialize()

    go func() {
        <-s.Comms.AppCount
    }()

    Convey("TestListApplication", t, func() {
        s.Comms.MainWaitGroup.Add(1)

        application := &Application{}
        err := json.Unmarshal(applicationJSON(), application)
        So(err, ShouldBeNil)

        revisions := &Revisions{}
        err = json.Unmarshal(revisionsJSON(), revisions)
        So(err, ShouldBeNil)

        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            line := <-s.Comms.Msg
            So(line, ShouldEqual, "3        admin       foo\n")
        }()
        s.listApplication(application, revisions)
        wg.Wait()
    })
}
```

The error here:

```
86 assertions thus far

..
88 assertions thus far

panic: Convey operation made without context on goroutine stack.
Hint: Perhaps you meant to use `Convey(..., func(c C){...})` ?

goroutine 115 [running]:
runtime.panic(0x350d80, 0xc208083050)
    /Users/administrator/jenkins/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.golang.GolangInstallation/1.3.1/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:279 +0xf5
github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/convey.conveyPanic(0x4960d0, 0x78, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/administrator/jenkins/workspace/tropoCLI/golang/src/github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/convey/context.go:20 +0x6a
github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/convey.mustGetCurrentContext(0x5ecea0)
    /Users/administrator/jenkins/workspace/tropoCLI/golang/src/github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/convey/context.go:52 +0x57
github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/convey.So(0x2d78e0, 0xc208001e80, 0x48f210, 0xc208001e60, 0x1, 0x1)
    /Users/administrator/jenkins/workspace/tropoCLI/golang/src/github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/convey/doc.go:123 +0x1e
_/Users/administrator/jenkins/workspace/tropoCLI.func¬∑048()
    /Users/administrator/jenkins/workspace/tropoCLI/tropoCLI_test.go:222 +0x17d
created by _/Users/administrator/jenkins/workspace/tropoCLI.func¬∑049
    /Users/administrator/jenkins/workspace/tropoCLI/tropoCLI_test.go:223 +0x398

goroutine 16 [chan receive]:
testing.RunTests(0x48f340, 0x5ed680, 0x29, 0x29, 0x48f701)
    /Users/administrator/jenkins/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.golang.GolangInstallation/1.3.1/src/pkg/testing/testing.go:505 +0x923
testing.Main(0x48f340, 0x5ed680, 0x29, 0x29, 0x5f5b40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x5f5b40, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/administrator/jenkins/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.golang.GolangInstallation/1.3.1/src/pkg/testing/testing.go:435 +0x84
main.main()
    _/Users/administrator/jenkins/workspace/tropoCLI/_test/_testmain.go:127 +0x9c
```

Answer (score 11):

Because you are trying to perform an assertion from another goroutine, you'll need to make use of the recently added context struct (`C`) in the `func()` signature, then call `So` off of that context. Here's your version with a slight modification:

```
Convey("TestListApplication", t, func(c C) {
    s.Comms.MainWaitGroup.Add(1)

    application := &Application{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(applicationJSON(), application)
    So(err, ShouldBeNil)

    revisions := &Revisions{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(revisionsJSON(), revisions)
    So(err, ShouldBeNil)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        line := <-s.Comms.Msg
        c.So(line, ShouldEqual, "3        admin       foo\n")
    }()
    s.listApplication(application, revisions)
    wg.Wait()
})
```

This was a result of pull [request #264](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/pull/264).

Answer (score 0):

This exception is launched by [`context.go#mustGetCurrentContext()`](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/blob/85ff0f6b4a4674ae1523510d1793b0ee4f829a30/convey/context.go#L49-L55).
you can see a test triggering that same exception in [`story_conventions_test.go#TestFailureModeNoContext`](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/blob/9f800fa7d56a5bb44514a4b3463f3f4d21346b78/convey/story_conventions_test.go#L93-L103)

```
Convey("Foo", t, func() {
    done := make(chan int, 1)
    go func() {
        defer func() { done <- 1 }()
        defer expectPanic(t, noStackContext)
        So(len("I have no context"), ShouldBeGreaterThan, 0)
    }()
    <-done
})
```

From the test example, if seems that calling a goroutine from within a goroutine from within a Convey test would trigger the no context panic.

Since Jenkins launches the tests from a goroutine, that might explain why your GoConvey test fails (even though it runs when you are calling `go test` directly, outside of Jenkins)